# findViewById returns null when invoked from non-Activity

Tags: android, scala

I am attempting to develop an Android application using Scala.

When my application launches it immediately displays a dialog as follows:

```
override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)   
    competitionSetupDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), HomeScreenActivity.CompetitionDialog)
  }  

  override def onStart() {
    super.onStart
    resourceHelper.setActivity(this)
  }
```

My fragment is as follows:

```
class CompetitionSetupDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
  @Inject
  var competitionSetupDialogHandler: CompetitionSetupDialogHandler = null
  @Inject
  var resourceHelper: ResourceHelper = null

  override def onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog = {
    val builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.competitionSetupDialogMessage))
      .setCancelable(false)
      .setView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.competition_setup, null))
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new OnClickListener {
        def onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {
          dismiss()
        }
      })
      .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new OnClickListener {
        def onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {
          val competitionNameInput = resourceHelper.findViewById(R.id.competitionNameInput).asInstanceOf[EditText]
          val numberOfPlayersInput = resourceHelper.findViewById(R.id.numberOfPlayersInput).asInstanceOf[EditText]
          val numberOfSubsInput = resourceHelper.findViewById(R.id.numberOfSubsInput).asInstanceOf[EditText]
          val lengthOfHalfInput = resourceHelper.findViewById(R.id.lengthOfHalfInput).asInstanceOf[EditText]
          competitionSetupDialogHandler.retrieveValuesAndSave(competitionNameInput, numberOfPlayersInput, numberOfSubsInput, lengthOfHalfInput)
        }
      })

    builder.create()
  }
}
```

Lastly, the ResourceHelper contains the following:

```
public View findViewById(int viewID) {
        return activity.findViewById(viewID);
    }
```

My problem is that my resourceHelper.findViewById always returns null, even though these are valid views.

My thinking is that by the time the onClick() is invoked, the view has been destroyed, or something similar.
How can I get around this issue?

One thing to add here is that my dialog displays fine, it is only when onClick is performed that I have an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this as follows:

Created a dialog view variable:

```
var dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.competition_setup, null)
```

Used this variable to call findViewById:

```
val competitionNameInput = dialogView .findViewById(R.id.competitionNameInput).asInstanceOf[EditText]
```